# Updating entity without having the know primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given the following code,  how can I add an element to one of the properties of an entity without knowing its Id and retrieving it from the database?

```
    public async Task BookInPersonVisitAsync(Guid propertyId, DateTime dateTime, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var entity = new OnBoardingProcessEntity{ ExternalId = propertyId };

        DbContext.OnBoardingProcesses.Attach(entity);

        entity.OnBoardingProcessVisits.Add(new OnBoardingProcessVisitEntity
        {
            DateTime = dateTime,
            Occurred = false
        });

        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
    }
```

ExternalId is just a guid we use for external reference. This doesnt work cause it does not have the id set, but without hitting the database we cant have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With entity framework if you have to reference an entity (`referencedEntity`) from another entity (`entity`) you have to know `referencedEntity`.
Otherwise you can add just add the entity setting the `referencedEntity` to null.
To know the referencedEntity or you know the `Id` or you have to retrieve it in some ways (from the database).

In SQL (DML) if (and only if) `ExternalId` is a candidate key noy nullable you can insert the `OnBoardingProcessVisit` record with a single roundtrip but the insert statement will contain an inner query.

```
  OnBoardingProcessVisit.OnBoardingProcess_Id = (
    SELECT 
      Id 
    FROM 
      OnBoardingProcess 
    WHERE 
      ExternalId = @propertyId)
```

**EDIT**
No way to generate that query with EF. You can have a look to external components (free and not free, for example EntityFramework Extended but in this case I think that doesn't help).

In this case I probably would try to use standard entity framework features (so 1 roundtrip to retrieve the `OnBoardingProcess` from the `ExternalId`).
Then, if the roundtrip is too slow, run the SQL query directly on the database.
About performances (and database consistency) add a unique index on `OnBoardingProcess.ExternalId` (in every case).

Another suggestion if you decide for the roundtrip.
In your code, the `entity` will be a proxy. If you don't disable lazy load, using your code you will do one more roundtrip when you will access to property 
`entity.OnBoardingProcessVisits` (in the statement `entity.OnBoardingProcessVisits.Add`).
So, in this case, disable lazy load or do the same using a different way.
The different way in your case is something like

```
var onBoardingProcessVisitEntity  new OnBoardingProcessVisitEntity
{
    DateTime = dateTime,
    Occurred = false,
    OnBoardingProcess = entity
});

DbContext.OnBoardingProcessVisits.Add(onBoardingProcessVisitEntity);
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
```

Comment: thank you for you input, The thing is, how do I make the EF generate a script just like in your example? There is now way I can say in EF that the external id is a candidate key.

Comment: It seems I would be able to just use HasAlternateKey in newest versions of the EF :( Thanks for your help.